# How to display DataTable row so that it uses multiple row space as the count of columns is more than 20

Tags: vue.js, templates, datatable, primevue

I have Datatable and want to display the row in a way that uses multiple row space as the number of columns is more than 20. I tried custom css but seems like not working. I am using v-for for columns to loop through.

```
 <DataTable
      :value="formattedSearchResults"
      dataKey="_id"
      responsiveLayout="scroll"
      :stripedRows="true"
      :rowHover="true"
      rowGroupMode="subheader"
      :row-class="rowClass"
      groupRowsBy="_id"
      :expandableRowGroups="true"
      v-model:expandedRowGroups="expandedHFRowGroups"
      @rowgroupExpand="onHFRowGroupExpand"
      @rowgroupCollapse="onHFRowGroupCollapse"
    >
      <template #empty> No results found. </template>
      <template #loading> Searching... </template>
      <template #groupheader="slotProps">
        <span>
          <v-icon icon="mdi-horse"></v-icon>
          <b>&nbsp;{{ slotProps.data.name }}</b> ({{
            slotProps.data.form_count
          }})</span
        >
      </template>
        <Column
          v-for="col in setHeadersForEntity()"
          :field="col.field"
          :key="col.field"
        >
          <template #body="slotProps">
            <div class="flex align-items-center gap-1">
              {{ formatColumnValue(slotProps) }}
            </div>
          </template>
        </Column>

      <Column
        headerStyle="width: 4rem; text-align: center"
        bodyStyle="text-align: center; overflow: visible"
      >
        <template #body="slotProps">
          <Button
            type="button"
            icon="pi pi-pencil"
            class="p-button-rounded p-button-text p-button-result-edit"
            @click="editEntity(slotProps.data, this.$route.query.entity)"
          ></Button>
          <Button
            type="button"
            icon="pi pi-times"
            class="p-button-rounded p-button-danger p-button-text p-button-result-delete"
            @click="deleteEntity(slotProps.data, this.$route.query.entity)"
          ></Button>
        </template>
      </Column>
    </DataTable>
```

How to fix this issue? is it possible to wrap template in a div or should I have to consider other Table component other than DataTable?

Answer (score 1):

You can Wrap your `Column` components within a `div` element and apply a custom CSS class to the `div` to control the layout like this:

```
<template>
  <DataTable
    :value="formattedSearchResults"
    dataKey="_id"
    responsiveLayout="scroll"
    :stripedRows="true"
    :rowHover="true"
    rowGroupMode="subheader"
    :row-class="rowClass"
    groupRowsBy="_id"
    :expandableRowGroups="true"
    v-model:expandedRowGroups="expandedHFRowGroups"
    @rowgroupExpand="onHFRowGroupExpand"
    @rowgroupCollapse="onHFRowGroupCollapse"
  >
    <template #empty> No results found. </template>
    <template #loading> Searching... </template>
    <template #groupheader="slotProps">
      <span>
        <v-icon icon="mdi-horse"></v-icon>
        <b>&nbsp;{{ slotProps.data.name }}</b> ({{ slotProps.data.form_count }})
      </span>
    </template>
    
    <div class="custom-row">
      <Column
        v-for="col in setHeadersForEntity()"
        :field="col.field"
        :key="col.field"
      >
        <template #body="slotProps">
          <div class="flex align-items-center gap-1">
            {{ formatColumnValue(slotProps) }}
          </div>
        </template>
      </Column>

      <Column
        headerStyle="width: 4rem; text-align: center"
        bodyStyle="text-align: center; overflow: visible"
      >
        <template #body="slotProps">
          <Button
            type="button"
            icon="pi pi-pencil"
            class="p-button-rounded p-button-text p-button-result-edit"
            @click="editEntity(slotProps.data, this.$route.query.entity)"
          ></Button>
          <Button
            type="button"
            icon="pi pi-times"
            class="p-button-rounded p-button-danger p-button-text p-button-result-delete"
            @click="deleteEntity(slotProps.data, this.$route.query.entity)"
          ></Button>
        </template>
      </Column>
    </div>
  </DataTable>
</template>

<style scoped>
.custom-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
</style>
```

I wrapped the `Column` components in a `div` with the class `custom-row`. Then, I applied CSS to make the `div` display as a flex container with wrapping. This allows the columns to span multiple rows if there are more than 20 columns. You can adjust the CSS as needed to achieve the desired layout.